# How to have separate home function for menu that loads divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu that is set to hide/show divs in the main body of the page. It functions but I need to have preloaded content inside that main body div. I have it now so when you click the menu items it hides the initial content.

I need the home menu item set to show that main div again as well as hide whatever content is currently showing...

```js
// JavaScript Document
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.menu').click(function () {
            var $clicked = $(this)
            $('.menu').each(function(){
                var $menu = $(this);
                if (!$menu.is($clicked))
                {
                    $($menu.attr('data-item')).hide();
                        $('#homecontent').hide();
                }
            });
            $($clicked.attr('data-item')).toggle();
         });
                    $('#home-menu-item').click(function () {
                        $('homecontent').show();
                });
            window.onresize = function(){
                var img = document.getElementById('fullsize');
                img.style.width = "100%";
            };
    });
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #151515;
 background: url('media/Shadexbackground_000000.png') no-repeat;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-size: cover;
}footer {
 height: 2vh;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 3vh;
 margin-right: 3vh;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
header {
 height: 11vh;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
}

#wrapper {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
}
#bodycontent {
 opacity: .4;
 height: 75vh;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #2A2A2A;
 margin-top: 2vh;
 margin-bottom: 5vh;
 margin-left: 3vh;
 margin-right: 3vh;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
.logoclass {
 width: 100%;
 height: 90%;
 min-width: 0px;

}
#topmenu {
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 font-size: 2.5vmin;
 text-align: center;
 word-spacing:  10vw;
}


#logo img {
 border-radius: 0;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: lesterbold;
 src: url(../fonts/lesterbold.woff);
 font-size: medium;
} 
@font-face {
 font-family: vipna;
 src: url(../fonts/vipnagorgialla.woff);
} 
#topmenu a:link, a:visited {
 color: #E7E7E7;
 border-radius: 0;
 font-family: lesterbold;
 /* [disabled]font-size: 14pt; */
 text-decoration: none;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: lighter;
 text-shadow: 1px 0px 1px rgba(255, 150, 150, 0.82), 0px 0px 1px rgba(150, 255, 150, 0.95), -1px 0px 1px rgba(150, 150, 255, 0.82), 0 0 10px #E7E7E7 , 0 0 15px #E7E7E7;
}

#topmenu a:hover, a:active {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 border-radius: 0;
 font-family: lesterbold;
 /* [disabled]font-size: 14pt; */
 text-decoration: none;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: lighter;
 text-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffffff , 0 0 15px #ffffff , 0 0 20px #ffffff;
}#footerleft {
 float: left;
 width: 45vw;
 text-align: left;
 padding-left: 5vm;
}
#footerright {
 float: right;
 width: 45vw;
 text-align: right;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-left: 5vw;
}
#videobox {
 text-align: left;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-family: vipna;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: lighter;
 font-size: 2.5vmin;
 width: 50vw;
 max-width: 100%;
 margin-left: 25vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Begin content -->
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
<div align="center" class="logoclass" id="logo"><img src="media/logo.png"/></div>
<div id="topmenu">
<a href="#" id="home-menu-item" class="menu" data-item="#menu-home">Home</a>
<a href="#" id="videos-menu-item" class="menu" data-item="#menu-videos">Videos</a>
<a href="#" id="follow-menu-item" class="menu" data-item="#menu-follow">Follow</a>
<a href="#" id="contact-menu-item" class="menu" data-item="#menu-contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</header>

<article>
<div id="bodycontent">
<!--Contact -->
<div id="menu-contact" style="display: none">Contact</div>
<!--Follow -->
<div id="menu-follow" style="display: none">Follow</div>
<!--Videos -->
<div id="menu-videos" style="display: none"><br />
<div id="videos" style="z-index:1" onClick="document.getElementById('sitemusic').pause();"><br />
<div align="center" id="videobox">Splash
<video style="z-index:-1;" width="400" controls>
  <source src="media/videos/splash.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="media/videos/splash.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--Home -->
<div id="homecontent">.dfsg5r4y5g4b</div>
</div>
</article>
```

Comment: A JSfiddle or similar would be helpful here.

Comment: I attached the scripts into the post. You can run code snippet just like jsfiddle. I am new to stackoverflow so if that is not good enough let me know and I will create a jsfiddle link

Comment: you code refers to locally hosted files, so it's useless from everyone else's point of view.

Comment: It seems you can just change `id="homecontent"` to `id="menu-home"`?

Comment: If I do that then it auto hides it on page load. But that div i want to show on load but then get replaced once a menu item is clicked... and then show again if you click home.